# Terminal gets blocked when opening Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

as I have set the Path variable to point to the "bin" folder of *Intellij* I can project from the command line by navigating to the specific folder and then executing `idea .`.

The problem now is that when starting *Intellij* the console is blocked. I can of course press `Ctrl + C` to end the execution but then *Intellij* is closed.

a) Is this the normal behavior or did I set something up wrong?
b) How do I change it? Basically I would like open “Intellij” and still be abel to use the console afterwards.

I am using the *Intellij Idea Community Edition* on version 2021.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. The termial accepted the command and is waiting for it to terminate. You could start the command and let it run in the background, so the terminal returns, and the process does not stop:

On Linux:

```
idea . &
```

On Windows:

```
start /B idea .
```